# Receiving step counter events when app is not in the foreground

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I want my app to be informed anytime the step counter sensor detects a step. As said in the doc, I register a listener for this sensor and never unregister it. I have also tried to launch a `JobService` at a regular interval, then tried to launch a `PeriodicWorker`, but this two objects are only informed of a step count change when the app comes back to the foreground, which is useless as the app is informed as well.
Does anyone know how my app can receive step counter events even if it is in the foregroung or killed?

Comment: Have you tried using a foreground service for this task?

Comment: As my app is supposed to monitor step count 24 hours a day, I think foreground service is not a good idea, considering energy efficiency.

Comment: A foreground service us actually the most reliable way of going about this task. Use anything else and the system will kill it even before it gets the chance to perform any operation

Comment: `PeriodicWorker`s aren't immediately killed by the system. Otherwise, they would be completely unuseful. As far as I have analysed my logs, the `Worker` receives step count changes but only if the phone user is moving when it is started (no matter if the app is running, in the background or killed). If the phone is still, the `Worker`is started, but never gets the step count.